# Perl - difference between 'next' and 'continue'?

Tags: perl, loops

Quick Perl question: when going through a loop (say a while loop), what is the difference between a `next` and `continue` command? I thought both just skip to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Short answer.  Perl `next` is like Java and most other languages' `continue`.  Use a named label on your loop.  Perl `continue` would rarely be used.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `continue` keyword can be used *after* the block of a **loop**. The code in the `continue` block is executed before the next iteration (before the loop condition is evaluated). It does not affect the control-flow.

```
my $i = 0;
when (1) {
  print $i, "\n";
}
continue {
  if ($i < 10) {
    $i++;
  } else {
    last;
  }
}
```

Is almost equivalent to

```
foreach my $i (0 .. 10){
  print $i, "\n";
}
```

The `continue` keyword has another meaning in the `given`-`when` construct, Perl's `switch`-`case`. After a `when` block is executed, Perl automatically `break`s because most programs do that anyway. If you want to *fall through* to the next cases the `continue` has to be used. Here, `continue` modifies the control flow.

```
given ("abc") {
  when (/z/) {
    print qq{Found a "z"\n};
    continue;
  }
  when (/a/) {
    print qq{Found a "a"\n};
    continue;
  }
  when (/b/) {
    print qq{Found a "b"\n};
    continue;
  }
}
```

Will print

```
Found a "a"
Found a "b"
```

The `next` keyword is only available in loops and causes a new iteration incl. re-evaluation of the loop condition. `redo` jumps to the beginning of a loop block. The loop condition is not evaluated.

Comment: Hi, could you give an example contrasting the continue and next ?

Comment: It's not true that `next` is "only available in loops". You can actually `next` out of a non-loop block and Perl won't stop you; it's just not very useful *or* very kind to the reader of your code.

Comment: @hobbs Of course, but only *if the block is named*. `if(1){next}` fails although there is a syntactic block. `sub foo{next} foo()` fails although there is a syntactic block. Only *named blocks* like `FOO:{next}` work. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @amon It doesn't have to be named, it just has to be a bare block, not belonging to an if. `for (1..3) { print "a"; { next; print "b" } print "c" }` prints "acacac" not "aaa".

Comment: There is a typo in the first code block, I suspect you ment `while(1) { ..` not `when(1) { ...`

Answer (score 2):

Execution of *next* statement will skip executing the rest of the statements in the loop for that particular iteration.

Statements in the *continue* block will execute for each and every iteration, irrespective of whether the loop executed as usual or the loop needs to terminate the particular iteration by encountering the *next* statement.

Example without *continue* block:

```
my $x=0;
while($x<10)
{
    if($x%2==0)
    {
        $x++; #incrementing x for next loop when the condition inside the if is satisfied.
        next;
    }
    print($x."\n");
    $x++;  # incrementing x for the next loop 
}
```

In the above example, the incrementation of x needs to be written 2 times. But if we use the continue statement which can hold the statements that need to be executed all the time we can increment x only one time inside the continue loop.

```
my $x=0;
while($x<10)
{
    if($x%2==0)
    {
        next;
    }
    print($x."\n");
}
continue
{
        $x++;
}
```

output in both cases are 1,3,5,7,9